# Gridview with Template Fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I think I was approaching this the wrong way. So I decided to implement the master details formview example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581796.aspx

So now when a user selects a record it populates in the formview and I added an update button that changes the mode of the formview to edit and all is well.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was approaching this the wrong way. So I decided to implement the master details formview example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581796.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the controls from an edit template directly on rowdatabound.  Something like...

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && 
    (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    { 
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlHours");
        //Manipulate ddl here
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my code to do as you said seems like I am closer but not there yet. For some reason the label displays the correct value but the dropdownlist inside my edititemtemplate named ddlStartHour is not displaying the correct selected value on edit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looping through the data while populating the dropdownlist and setting the selected value by matching it to the label?

```
//Perform loop here
if (label.text == ddl.SelectedValue)
   ddl.Items.FindByValue(i.ToString()).Selected = true;
```